# Replace characters in Makefile target

Tags: make, replace

I'm trying to use

```
$(patsubst %-%,%:%,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

to replace dashes with colons in the make target but it has no effect.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only have a single wildcard in `patsubst`. To replace all dashes with colons, you can use [`subst`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-subst-1):

```
$(subst -,:,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tr` command:

```
tr '-' ':' < OLD_MAKE_TARGET > NEW_MAKE_TARGET
```